# Get the area of polygon with drawpolygon()-function

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure

[image]

```
image = imread('test.png');
imshow(image);
    
polygon = drawpolygon('Linewidth', 3, 'Color', 'red');
disp(polygon);
```

Hello, I'm new to Matlab and programming. I'm trying to get the area of the drop (tried a few things with the Image Processing Toolbox but the results weren't good enough as it was hard to detect just the drop).

With the `drawcircle()` function I could get the Radius of it after drawing. With `disp(polygon)` however I only get following information:

```
           Position: [22×2 double]
              Label: ''
              Color: [1 0 0]
             Parent: [1×1 Axes]
            Visible: on
           Selected: 0
           Children: [0×0 GraphicsPlaceholder]
              Color: [1 0 0]
        ContextMenu: [1×1 ContextMenu]
          Deletable: 1
        DrawingArea: 'auto'
          EdgeAlpha: 1
          FaceAlpha: 0.2000
     FaceSelectable: 1
   HandleVisibility: 'on'
InteractionsAllowed: 'all'
              Label: ''
         LabelAlpha: 1
     LabelTextColor: [0 0 0]
       LabelVisible: 'on'
          LineWidth: 3
         MarkerSize: 6
             Parent: [1×1 Axes]
           Position: [22×2 double]
           Selected: 1
      SelectedColor: 'none'
        StripeColor: 'none'
                Tag: ''
               Type: 'images.roi.polygon'
           UserData: []
            Visible: on
```

Is there any way to get the vertices of the polygon after drawing it manually?
(As far as I know you can get the area with "polyarea" if you have the vertices)

Comment: Does the `Position` property not give you the data you need? Since it's a two column array I suspect it's your `x` and `y` coordinates...

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I needed.